# How to visually highlight text between these tags?

Tags: neovim, visual-mode

I'm new to Vim and trying to create a book how practical applications of Vim key bindings to R and Quarto based workflows.

Using R with Quarto we will typically encourage two code blocks:

````
```{r}
#| label: something
#| fig-width: 10
#| fig-cap: "something"
#| echo: false
#| eval: true

plot<- diamonds %>%
ggplot(aes(x=price,y=carat))+
geom_point()

```
````

I really like the key binding of `vi`{tag} e.g. `vi`{the thing you want to grab between} to quickly highlight to yank, edit or copy.

However, I don't know how to do that with the below scenarios (referencing the above code chunk)

1. how to grab everything between the opening ```` ``` ```` and the closing ```` ``` ````
2. how to grab the code meta data (everything that has `#|`)
3. how to grab just the code section within the code junk (e.g. plot downwards)

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'tag' concept in your question is called `text-object` in the Vim documentation.

There are various text objects defined. Some standard text-object can be used to address part of your question (Paragraph), some plugin defined text-object can be used for some other part (Multi Line String) and some custom text objects are needed to address the rest.

### Paragraph

To select an entire paragraph (all the lines separated by blank lines) you can do: `vip` (using the underlying `ip` text-object. More information with `:help text-objects`)

### Multi Lines String

To select everything between ```` ``` ```` and ```` ``` ```` you need an extension of the `` i` `` text-object that support multi-lines strings.

If you install the [target](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) plugin, to select everything between `` ` `` you can do: `` vi` ``.

Remark: Since on some keyboards the backtick character: `` ` `` is a dead key (i.e.: it produce a character only in combination to the next character you type) you may need to type `` vi` ``  with a trailing space (i.e.: `` vi` ``<kbd>space</kbd>).

### Custom Text Object

To select the set of contiguous lines that starts with `#|` you need to define a specific text object for that.

If you add the following lines to your `.vimrc` file a new `im` text-object will be defined.

```
vnoremap im <ESC>$?\v(^#\\|.*$\n)@<!^#\\|<CR>:normal! V<CR>/\v^#\\|.*$(\n^#\\|)@!<CR>
omap im :normal Vim<CR>
```

With this `im` text object you could select the block with: `vim`.

#### Explanation

The first line makes `im` extend the selection to the entire block in `Visual` mode:

```
vnoremap im <ESC>$?\v(^#\\|.*$\n)@<!^#\\|<CR>:normal! V<CR>/\v^#\\|.*$(\n^#\\|)@!<CR>
```

1. `<ESC>` leaves Visual mode
2. `$` goes at the end of the line
3. `?\v(^#\|.*$)@<!^#\|<CR>` search for the previous occurrence of a line starting with `#|` that is not preceded by a line starting with `#|` (in the `vnoremap` the `|` need to be escaped `\|`)
4. `:normal! V<CR>` enter in Visual mode
5. `/\v^#\|(\n^#\|)@!<CR>` search for the next occurrence of a line starting with `#|` that is not followed by a line starting with `#|`

The total extend the visual selection to the set of contiguous lines starting with `#|`.

The second line defines an operator pending action for `im`

```
omap im :normal Vim<CR>
```

You enter the operator pending mode when Vim is waiting keys to complete an action (e.g. when you type `y` in normal mode Vim is waiting a move or a text object specifier to know what to yank exactly)

Remark: Since this mapping make use of the previously defined `im` mapping we can't use the non-recursive version of `omap`. If we would we should have to repeat the sequence previously defined.

With this one it select the entire block. Hence `yim` will yank the entire block, `cim` will change the entire block, `dim` will deleted the entire block.

Comment: Thanks for the education!

The vi’ combo doesn’t work for me though. Does my cursor need to be in a special place?

Comment: The combo need to use the back thick `vi\`` which is different from `vi'`. Since `\`` is a deadkey on my keyboard I have to type: `vi\` ` (including a trailing space)

Comment: I'll explain more about the text object tomorrow ;-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt is the backtick text object standard? I feel like I might have a mapping for that, or at least that it doesn’t work perfectly with triple-backticks.

Comment: i` is indeed standard but it only works if the backticks are on the same line.

Comment: Thanks @romainl I have updated the solution to mention the [target](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) plugin that get rid of that multi-line string limit.